# JQuery Multi File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload

I have a problem in which I need to upload multiple files using multipart POST request,
I need a single browse button to choose the uploaded files.
I've seen [JQuery Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Overview) for multi file upload, but there is a problem that only one file is uploaded several times. the post request file parameters are sent with the same name.
My question is how to deal with this behaviour so that file params are sent with different names?

Here is the my HTML:

```
<form id="uploadFormId" name="uploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://...">
<input type="file" name="MultiFile" id="uploadFileId" class="multi"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to post some code... sounds like you've made a mistake somewhere. The jQuery plugin definately works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your files name an array, as in:

```
    <input type="file" name="MultiFile[]" id="uploadFileId" class="multi"/>
```

then when checking for your $_FILES, you run a "foreach" php command.